# Stellar moves on pairs of polyhedra

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, convex-polytopes, polyhedra

Let $P$ and $Q$ be polyhedra of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $Q \subset P$.  Let $(M,N)$ and $(M',N)$ be pairs of *abstract* simplicial complexes.

Consider two triangulations
$$f\colon (|M|,|N|) \to (P,Q)$$
and 
$$f\colon (|M'|,|N|) \to (P,Q).$$

By a "triangulation"  we mean a homeomorphism $f\colon |M| \to P$ ($|M|$ being the geometric realisation of $M$) which is linear (or more correctly affine) in each simplex of $M$ and such that $f$ sends $|N|$ to $Q$.

Suppose that the restrictions of $f$ and $f'$ to $|N|$ coincide.

Is this true?

There exists a stellar subdivision $S$ of $N$, inducing star subdivisions $T$ and $T'$ of $M$ and $M'$ and a sequence of abstract simplicial complexes:
$$ (T,S) \to (T_1,S) \to (T_2,S) \to \dots \to (T_n,S)=(T',S),$$
where $T_i$ is obtained from $T_{i-1}$ from a stellar subdivision, inverse stellar subdivision, both along simplices which do not belong to $S$, or a simplicial isomorphism which is the identity in $S$.

I can sort of concoct a proof by looking at the proof of Alexander's theorem appearing Glasser's book "Geometrical combinatorial topology, Volume 1." But I presume someone else has seriously thought about these issues before?

I have read discussions on relative Alexander theorem and relative Pachner theorem (namely "V.G. and Viro, O.Ya.; State sum invariants of 3-manifolds and quantum 6jsymbols, Topology 31 4, (1992) 865902" and "Casali, Maria Rita, A note about bistellar operations on PL-manifolds with boundary,” Geometria Dedicata 56 (1995) 257-262.") but they  seem to miss the necessity (which I am not convinced cannot be removed) of previously breaking the smaller polyhedron by means of a stellar subdivision (which again appears to be implied in Glasser's book).